# Magento duplicating a product programmatically is not displaying in the frontend

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am new to magneto I have tried to duplicate a product programmatically and I have succeeded problem is the duplicated product is showing in magneto admin side while in the frontend the product is not displaying below is my code could you please tell me what is the issue it will be very helpful for me. I have created a separate module for it below is my code.

```
class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
    public function indexAction() {
        $final = $_POST['value'];
        $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_product = $obj->load($final); 
        $newProduct = $_product->duplicate();

        $newProduct->setStatus(1);


        $newProduct->setSku('value'.$final);
         $newProduct->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());
        $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function posted by you very well creates **Duplicate** product. However, it does not set the below attribute (due to which it's not VISIBLE in the frontend):

> 1. Navigate to Catalog > Manage Products > Duplicated Product > Inventory

**Qty is 0** and **Stock is "Out of Stock"** - You will need to write below piece of code in the function to set this product to *Stock: "In Stock"* and *Qty: [some default value] say, 100*.

After the line which calls out `$newProduct->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());`, you can insert the below lines:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($newProduct->getId());
if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 && $stockItem->getManageStock())
{
    $qty = 100; //set a default max value
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
    $stockItem->save();
}
```

> 2. You will need to run a Re-Index either Manually or Automate it

The product will display in the frontend. See Screenshot below:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

Use the below code and let me know if it works for you:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $productId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('value');
    $productObject  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $_product   = $productObject->load($productId);

    $newProduct = $_product->duplicate();

    $newProduct->setStatus(1);
    //$newProduct->setName('Duplicate-' . $_product->getName());
    $newProduct->setSku('value' . $productId);
    $newProduct->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());

    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($newProduct->getId());
    if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 && $stockItem->getManageStock())
    {
        $qty = 100;
        $stockItem->setQty($qty);
        $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
        $stockItem->save();
    }

    $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);

    $indexers = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
    foreach ($indexers as $indexer)
    {
        $indexer->reindexEverything();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding...

Comment: the qty remains zero only and how to reindex where should I want to write the code?

Comment: The above answer is tested in CE 1.9.2.2 and it works (have shared the screenshot). Re-Indexing code also can be written within the same function.

Comment: I have posted an updated answer. Pls use that code and see if it works as expected. This contains Reindexing code.

Comment: I used the same code you mentioned in your answer but still I dont get the solution I have same issue only the product is not displaying in the frontend another thing is quantity is still zero in the admin side only

Comment: Not sure how this does not work for you. Are you missing something? Maybe you can tell me the version of Magento you are using.

Comment: this is my magento version Magento ver. 1.8.0.0

Comment: Works fine for me. You might need to check what's the $_product variable returning and $newProduct is showing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103075/discussion-between-shivani-and-sri).